# Why keys are compared in a strange way in HashMap.put()?

Tags: java, optimization, reference, hashmap

While skimming through the code of put() of HashMap, I came across a strange piece of code. Consider the below excerpt of code:

```
490  public V put(K key, V value) {
491        if (table == EMPTY_TABLE) {
492            inflateTable(threshold);
493     }
494  if (key == null)
495   return putForNullKey(value);
496     int hash = hash(key);
497     int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
498     for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
499         Object k;
500         if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
501             V oldValue = e.value;
502             e.value = value;
503             e.recordAccess(this);
504             return oldValue;
505         }
506     }
```

In line 500, why the key is assigned to a new variable `k` and then used in the OR condition? Why can't it be written directly as follows:

```
if (e.hash == hash && (e.key == key || key.equals(e.key))) {
```

I don't know why it is written that way, But I am sure there is some reason behind why it is coded so. Is it some kind of optimization? 
Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

They are saving an object dereference.

```
(e.key == key || key.equals(e.key))
```

That has to follow e->key twice.

This follows it once:

```
((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))
```

The saving is tiny though, and in modern compilers/optimizers/etc may even be no saving at all. Remember this code was written a long time ago and most likely by someone come from a C++ programming background where this sort of thing was both more common and more useful.

With a very frequent operation on a very frequently accessed class it may make sense. For most cases though the miniscule savings would not compensate for the loss of readability.